# Where is this code with Entity Framework 6.44 executed?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have property `A` with a `ICollection<A>` if I then make an alias like (T is A)

```cs
public virtual T Children
{ 
    get 
    {
        return ICollection<T>;
    }
    set
    {
         ICollection<T> = value;
    }
}
```

where is the lookup of entities executed? In code or in SQL Server? How does EF like this solution?

Added: The problem... I have a 10year old legacy system with nHibernate(ver 1.X) and c#. It inherits in a chain to have the  classes written to database have certain markup.  Everyone inherits a set of groundproperties and the some have  have a child /parent relationship has (from legacy code)

```
public abstract class GroundpropertiesTreeBaseEntity<T> : GroundpropertiesEntity
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual T Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<T> Children { get; set; }
}
```

If I look in the database what has been generated every one has a parentID to itselfs entity.

But if I try this in EF the problem will be how T Parent foreign key will be named. It expect it to be type T and then _Id and not anything else. You can write alias for this but it will not solve the Id problem since you cant write [Foreignkey(GetType(T)+"_Id"]. If I cant get a solution to make this work have to really somereally insane solution which I rather not do since it would me to rewrite the entire system since so many methods using this syntax for it classes.

I hope this cleared this up.

Comment: This won't compile, what's your actual code?

Comment: Dont have it yet .. trying to find a solution to implement. I now that the alias is allowed. But not If I do It generic and/or try to where it will be executed. On the SQL server or in code...

Comment: `trying to find a solution to implement.` a solution for *what*? Map a table field to a property with a different name? You can do that either with the `Column` attribute of the fluent API in `OnModelCreating`. What you posted is a property, it won't execute at all

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem X and assume Y is the solution. When that doesn't work you ask about Y, not the real problem X. What's the real problem here? What does the *actual class and properties* look like? Why can't you use them the way they are?

Comment: Explain the real problem in the question itself, not what you think the solution will look like. The comment makes little sense - FKs *are* set at runtime. NH didn't set autogenerated FKs in memory either. Even in NH inheritance is only used for entities with an actual inheritance relation, mapped to specific tables. Anything else is C# code unrelated to the ORM. You keep describing attempted solutions, not the actual problem

Comment: `every generic class has the same collection names/properties` what does that mean? Are you trying to add some audit properties to entities? You can do that in both ORMs using interfaces. With both of them though, you have to remember they are *ORMs*, not object databases.

Comment: I wonder if I should in inherit the foreignkey attribute class and get the type of caller class and the fix the name... seems the best thing to do now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by writing [Foreignkey("ThegenericKeyName")] in everyclass. Not a good or beautiful solution to handle a generic baseclass but it solves the problem .

inherit the attribute foreignkey class and then add _Id to the name of the property that it was placed on and then send it to foreignkey attribute baseclass name property. But I was out of time so I went for the first solution.